# Could not open input file: make:auth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

This question may be repeated but i tried all solutions and none of them solve my problem.

I installed laravel 5.3 project via composer using `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel website "5.3.*"` at `/home/user/Documents` and when i try to run any `make` command like `php make:auth` or `php make:middleware`, i got this message in terminal `Could not open input file: make:auth` or `Could not open input file: make:middleware`. I've checked out all permission to write and delete also i tried to run as root, and while searching there is a solution to run `chmod +x artisan` but not working for me. I can not figure out what the problem is.
I faced this problem when i moved from linux mint 18 to fedora workstation 25. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the command correctly - Laravel's CLI tool is called `artisan` and it is located in the root of your project.

From the root of your project, the correct commands are:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

and

```
php artisan make:middleware
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your project-path

You can check all command for execute by use php artisan